# ng-model inside ng-repeat checkbox multiple selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to edit the "Group" of some elements in a table. For that i select the elements in the table with a checkbox and after with a select i try the group that i want. The problem is that for edit when i check the button i can't send the liftsideid that i need for edit and always appears like undefined.
I simplify with and example that i put in comments.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VFWyrQORIr0TQav6UYl7?p=preview

```
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" ng-click="updateGroup(selectedgroup, myliftsite)" ng-hide="edit"> Añadir al Grupo</button>
```

When i do the click of the button, i need the selectedgroup that it's work ok and in "myliftsite" i need the id.